# Dealing with circular inclusion in a parent/child class relationship

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

Assume I've made a class, say `Parent`, that has a composition relation with `Child`. The parent class holds a list of children.

I want all children to hold a reference to the parent, so every child holds a `Parent` pointer.

This will cause circular inclusion. I refer to `Child` in *parent.h* and I refer to `Parent` in *child.h*. Therefore `Parent` will need to include `Child`, which needs to include `Parent`.

What's the best way to work around this?

Comment: Why do the children need parent pointers?  This is probably a design flaw.

Comment: The children will also be used outside the `Parent` class. The code that uses the children doesn't know at first which parent they're assigned to.

Comment: Not having seen the code, I'd say there's a good chance John is right and this is a design flaw.

Comment: @Pieter:  I realize that you've accepted an answer and probably moved on with your life, but you should really reconsider your design.  If `Parent`s need to know about `Child`s and `Child`s need to know about `Parent`s, then something is not right, and it's going to come back to haunt you later when its 10 times harder to fix than it is now.

Comment: @John: My question relates to a project that I'm working on for my C++ class. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to discuss the design or code of my program with anyone other than the professor and her assistants, so I can only ask generalized abstract questions. I'd like to investigate the alleged design flaw, but I cannot disclose any details about my code so I'm afraid that will be impossible.

Comment: By the way, I've seen children keep a parent pointer before. Many classes in the Qt framework have a constructor that lets you supply a parent pointer. Example: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsscene.html

Comment: @Pieter:  I understand your constraints.  Your professor is not doing you any favors by teaching you to program with very a poor design.  This is a great example of why in the past 10 years I've never been able to hire a programmer straight from college that I didn't have to extensively retrain.  I'm not upset with you, keep in mind.  I'm upset with your professor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to use forward declaration:

```
//parent.h
class Child; //Forward declaration
class Parent
{
    vector<Child*> m_children;
};

//child.h
class Parent; //Forward declaration
class Child
{
    Parent* m_parent;
};
```

Comment: I would not recommend the `vector<Child*>` a `vector<Child>` would mean that the `Parent` owns the `Child`ren and would make memory management much easier. Of course there's still the issue of getting the copy constructor and assignment operator right because the `Child::m_parent` should be changed.

Comment: The parent could own the children even if they're declared as `Child*`. You'll of course have to provide correct value semantics for the `Parent` class.

Answer (score 3):

Since only a pointer of `Parent` is stored inside the `Child` class there is no need to do a `#include "parent.h"` in the `child.h` file. Use the forward declaration of `class Parent;` in `child.h` instead of inclding `parent.h` in there. In the source file of child i.e. `child.cpp` you can do `#include "parent.h"` to use the `Parent` methods.